# Sort Text lines with included numbers (date) by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've a small Problem. I habe in an Array some textlines like them:

```
[
    '20140708_____AtestY.cm5',
    '20140711_____Ctestyy.cm5',
    '20140711_____Dtestzz.cm5',
    '20140711_____SBtestyy.cm5'
]
```

As you can see they're with a date (declared as numbers - i'll divide them later), then the Filename.
i'am trying to sort them by date and this works only nearly.

with the code `arrayFileData.sort().reverse()` i have a sort by date, but after that it starts also to sort alphabetic.

it is possible to say, look only the date (Nubers)?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply your own comparator function to `[].sort` so it's possible to only look at the first 8 characters (the date part):

```
arrayFileData.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.substr(0,8) - b.substr(0,8); // you could swap a and b here
                                         // to get the array sorted in reverse order
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort